JHipster JDL with builtInEntity working for User entity but not for Authority entity
In my JDL, I have myEntity which has to be linked with JHipster built-in entities (User, Authority).
I tried relationship ManyToMany { myEntity to User with builtInEntity } which is working fine.
But when I tried relationship ManyToMany { myEntity to Authority with builtInEntity } it's not working.
I'm curious to know why we can't link Authority to any other custom table (primary key being a String instead of a number shouldn't be a problem I guess)
Also, please guide me how to make many-to-many relationship with Authority table.
